# AWS authentication requires a valid Date or x-amz-date header curl

Tags: curl, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying for simple image upload using cURL by passing the required headers that is requested by AWS but I'm getting the below error...

```
<Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>AWS authentication requires a valid Date or x-amz-date header</Message>
```

Below is the authorization header I'm passing in..

```
curl -X PUT -T "/some/file.jpg" \
-H "Host: bucket.s3.amazonaws.com" \
-H "Date: date" \
-H "Content-Type: image/jpg" \
-H "Authorization: AWS XXXXXXX:XXXXXXXXXX" \
  https://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/
```

and below is how the signature is made,

```
signature=`echo -en ${stringToSign} | openssl sha1 -hmac ${s3Secret} -binary | base64`
```

I've tried passing the date in stringToSign and in the headers, but no luck.. Please help ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed the issue.. Turns out the HTTP header need to be in RFC 7231 format. I formatted it and it worked., below is the format I used,

`date -jnu +%a,\ %d\ %h\ %Y\ %T\ %Z`

Comment: After reading through a dozen other comments about wrong Java / Joda versions, this finally helped me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

had similar issue but got:

`Date must be in ISO-8601 'basic format'`

which I used this to fix:

`$(date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")`